# Convert nested loop to single loop without if statements

Tags: for-loop, optimization

I have a nested for loop that must modify the elements `arr[1:N+1, 1:M+1]` of an array `arr[N+2][M+2]` (or more commonly in Python `arr = np.zeros(shape=(N+2, M+2))`. **How can I convert the nested for loop below to a single for loop without any if statements using Python without any 3rd party libraries?**

This is how the nested for loop currently looks:

```py
N = 2
M = 2
ncols = M+2

for i in range(1, N+1):
  for j in range(1, M+1):
    print(i, j, i*ncols + j)

# Output:
# 1 1 5
# 1 2 6
# 2 1 9
# 2 2 10
```

This is my attempt, but you'll notice I am not accessing the correct part of the array based on the indices in the output.

```py
for i in range(ncols+1, (N+1) * (M+1)):
    row = i // ncols
    cols = i % ncols
    print(row, col, row*ncols + col)

# Output:
# 1 1 5
# 1 2 6
# 1 3 7
# 2 0 8
```

The reason I want to do this is because my actual code is in `C` and the report generated by `gcc -O3 -fopt-info-vec-all -fopt-info-loop-all main.c` indicates that vectorization could not occur due to control flow and too many nestings of loop. I chose to write the code above in Python for brevity.

Comment: If you want a C solution, how about writing the example in C and using the `c` tag? Without proper tags, people are unlikely to find your question.

Comment: What does the array declaration look like? Why do you start at index 1 instead of index 0?

Comment: When you mention "N+2 rows and M+2 columns" there should be 4 rows and 4 columns, right?

Comment: "How can I convert this nested for loop to a single for loop without any if statements?" Why would you wanna do that?

Comment: I've updated the bottom of question for the reason for why i want to do this. I ended up just sticking with python due to the provided answer. I start at index 1 because the first and last row of the matrix are cells whose values are initialized once and then kept constant, the left and right columns of the matrix are ghost cells and are updated later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my fix :

```
N = 2
M = 2

ncols = M+2

#nested loop
for i in range(1, N+1):
  for j in range(1, M+1):
    print(i, j, i*ncols + j)

# Output:
# 1 1 5
# 1 2 6
# 2 1 9
# 2 2 10

#non-nested loop
for k in range(0, N * M):
    i = k // N +1
    j = k % N +1
    print(i, j, i*ncols + j)

# Output:
# 1 1 5
# 1 2 6
# 2 1 9
# 2 2 10
```

In case you are using an other language you can flip `//` to a `/` and cast the output to be an `int`

Comment: Unfortunately the OP just converted the whole question to C like one minute before you posted. I can do a rollback of their edit back to Python if you like and then the OP can ask a separate question about C.

Comment: I rolled back to python. One of the previous comments was to write the code in C so i switched to C. Nbd

Comment: A small tip, if possible try starting your loops from zero, it simplifies things and helps you think faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @WissemRouin! I think it definitely confused me trying to start from 1